# Count and display current number of agents on a path

Tags: anylogic

In AnyLogic I am trying to count and display the current number of agents moving on a single path or rather in a single "moveTo" block. After that, the travel speed of the agents should be dependent on the displayed number.
Is that even possible?

I've tried it with statistics and variable but I guess I don't know enough about it yet.
The "moveTo" blocks are linked with nodes between which the paths are.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code, I am setting the agents' speed to 10 if the number of agents in the moveTo block is greater than 10.

```
if( moveTo.size() > 10  ) {

  for( Agent a : moveTo ) {

     a.setSpeed(10);
  }

}
```

So you can get the number of agents in the moveTo block by using `.size()` and then you can change agent speeds using `.setSpeed()`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked and helped a lot. :)
If I get more issues I might come back to it.